# Ошибка Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32768 bytes)

Tags: php, wordpress

Делаю выгрузку заказов `woocommerce` в файл csv.
Процесс долгий и выдаёт эту ошибку `Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32768 bytes)`
В файле `wp-config.php` поставил значение `define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '512M' );`
но ошибка не пропадает всё-равно.
Как удалить эту ошибку?
также указывает на этот файл: `/wp-includes/wp-db.php:2030`
`2030: $this->result = mysqli_query( $this->dbh, $query );`

Comment: Такие вещи нало делать через wp-cli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '-1' );
```

По идее даст вам доступ к памяти сервера без ограничений. Еще два варианта:
Если у Вас есть доступ к PHP.ini файлу, изменить значение с 32M на, скажем, 1024M: memory_limit = 1024M ; Maximum amount of memory a script may consume (1024M)

Если у Вас нет доступа к этому конфигурационному файлу, попробуйте создать файл .htaccess с таким содержанием: php_value memory_limit 1024M

Comment: подскажите, а можно ли сделать, чтобы memory_limit 1024m срабатывал только на одной странице?

Comment: насколько знаю - нет, выделяется на весь проект.. все таки CMS не столь гибка в возможностях.

Comment: В php: `ini_set('memory_limit','2G');` например.